Generate Google C++ Unit Test Report from Test Explorer
Using this answer I was able to generate test report when "running" (Start Debuging F5) the test project.
However I need the report to be generated when running the tests through Test Explorer. The tests run correctly, BUT the report is not being generated when test explorer runs.
I have tried to set the --gtest_output output flag in test explorer options,  but no joy.
Ultimately, I need to be able to check the success/failure of tests outside of Visual Studio after running Test Explorer

